# Why can I bind to a (seemingly) invalid port in C?

Tags: c, sockets

I have made a basic client and server in C using BSD sockets. I am able to bind to a port number above 65535, and the client can connect to it. What am I doing wrong here?

Code:

```
int port = 999999;
...
serverAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
```

Comment: Enable warnings and you will see...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because htons takes a 16 bit argument and its input will be truncated.

Try this and see what you get:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int foo = 999999;
        int bar = ntohs(htons(foo));

        printf("%d\n", bar);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: any reference will fortify your answer.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: If you can't be bothered to look up htons no reference will help you.

Answer (score 2):

`htons` works with short integer. So it'll truncate the number to a 16-bit version. In this case you should use `htonl` which takes 32-bit integer. But it wont work then too. In `netinet/in.h` `sockaddr_in` is defined as,

```
struct sockaddr_in
  {
    __SOCKADDR_COMMON (sin_);
    in_port_t sin_port;         /* Port number.  */
    ....
  };
```

And `in_port_t` is defined as

```
/* Type to represent a port.  */
typedef uint16_t in_port_t;
```

Hence `sin_port` is a **16-bit integer**.  The truncation will take place here too.
So If you run the following code,

```
int main(){
    unsigned long l = 0x00010001;
    unsigned short s = 0x00;
    printf("l=0x%08lX\n", l);       
    printf("s=0x%08X\n", s=l);      
    printf("l=0x%08lX\n", l=s);    
    return 0;
}
```

Output will be

```
l=0x00010001
s=0x00000001
l=0x00000001
```

See how the high order bit is lost!
[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/Cr4T7U)